# How to stop WKWebView inheriting the previous page's viewport when navigating to a PDF?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` which displays an HTML page from the local filesystem.

The file contains the following `meta` tag to prevent the user from scrolling:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

This all works as expected. The page also contains a link to an externally-hosted PDF file. If the user navigates there, the user cannot pinch-to-zoom the PDF (although they can double tap to zoom in, they can't zoom out again).

It took me a while to work out why, but I eventually discovered that removing the aforementioned origin page's `meta` tag unlocked the full functionality of zooming the PDF. It seems that `WKWebView` is preserving the viewport for the PDF from the referring page. `UIWebView` doesn't do this.

- Is this expected behaviour of `WKWebView`?
- How do I prevent this behaviour, so that zooming is prevented for the HTML page, but is allowed when navigating to the PDF?